# complement of a function $f: \{2n | n\in \mathbb{N}_0 \}: n \rightarrow n+1$

Tags: calculus, functions, definition

i am reading a textbook here and i saw, there is notion of *Complement of a function*. or Negation of a function definiton, this is whow i understood but it is definitely wrong how i do it, i know. in the textbook i have a function $f$: 
$$f: \{2n | n\in \mathbb{N}_0 \}: n \rightarrow n+1$$

and they said, that its complement(Negation) is: $f': \{2n+1| n\in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$

how they are coming to this? Generally how do i find the complement of a function? isnot just the image of a given function?

**or the problem underlying is: how do i find the injective extension of a function using this complement?**

**DEFINITION** of how to find injective extension: 
in order to extend f with whole $\mathbb{N}$ to $F: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, one has to find the injective map $f'$ of complement of $\{2n | n\in \mathbb{N_0}$ in $\mathbb{N_0}$ to the complement of image of $f$.

thanks a lot for help

Comment: Can you perhaps quote directly from the book, precisely as it is given in the book. Make sure to include the relevant definitions.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, i think, i am confused. they took the complement of image set. and they call the complement of a function the function which is mapping to that complement image set. does it make sense?

Comment: no, it does not make sense. That is why I asked for the precise definitions from the book.

Comment: I can try it in German but can't make any guarantees

Comment: sorry, that doesn't help.

Comment: I think that I may see what’s going on; give me a few minutes to write it up.

Comment: I’ve given an answer that explains what’s going on in this problem, but it doesn’t completely explain the terminology. I find it hard to imagine using the term *complement* this way in English; what is the original language?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, it is in german. i think, in english it would mean negation or something.

Comment: I can read German; can you quote the wording?

Comment: here it is: 
**task**: Geben Sie eine injektive Fortsetzung der Abbildung f auf die Menge der natürlicher Zahlen $\mathbb{N_0}$ an
und beweisen Sie Ihre Behauptung.
**answer**: Um $f$ auf ganz $\mathbb{N}$ injektiv zu einer Abbildung $F: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ fortzusetzen, muss man eine injektive
Abbildung $f'$ vom Komplement von $\{2n | n \in \mathbb{N_0} \}$ in $\mathbb{N_0}$ in das Komplement des Bildes von f
angeben:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working very specifically from this particular example. You have the function

$$f:\{2n:n\in\Bbb N_0\}\to\Bbb N_0:n\mapsto n+1\;.$$

This function is an injection from the subset $\{2n:n\in\Bbb N_0\}$ of $\Bbb N_0$, and the problem is to extend it to an injection $F:\Bbb N_0\to\Bbb N_0$.

The idea is then to define a new function $f\,'$ so that if we then let

$$F:\Bbb N_0\to\Bbb N_0:n\mapsto\begin{cases}f(n),&\text{if }n\in\operatorname{dom}f\\f\,'(n),&\text{if }n\in\operatorname{dom}f\,'\;,\end{cases}$$

this $F$ will be an injection whose domain is all of $\Bbb N_0$. This means that the domain of $f\,'$ must be the complement of the domain of $f$: we want

$$\operatorname{dom}f\,'=\Bbb N_0\setminus\operatorname{dom}f=\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N_0\}\;,$$

the set of odd natural numbers. We also want $F$ to be injective, so we want to make sure that the range of $f\,'$ is disjoint from the range of $f$: we want $\operatorname{ran}f\,'\cap\operatorname{ran}f=\varnothing$, or, equivalently,

$$\operatorname{ran}f\,'\subseteq\Bbb N_0\setminus\operatorname{ran}f=\Bbb N_0\setminus\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N_0\}=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N_0\}\;.$$

That is, the range of $f\,'$ should be a subset of the complement of the range of $f$. In this case we can actually make the range of $f\,'$ all of the complement of the range of $f$: there is an easy bijection

$$f\,':\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N_0\}\to\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}\;;$$

it is in fact the *inverse* of the function $f$.